# How can I get Steam username and avatar image from leaderboard?

Tags: unity, c#, steam, steamworks

After I downloaded leaderboard data (using the Steamworks.NET API), I couldn't find any related info about the user's name and the avatar picture. The only thing I can get is a `CSteamID`.

I saw some games implement a Steam Leaderboard, displaying their name and avatar images, and I'm trying to achieve the same thing. However, I've searched on the Steamworks documentation and on Google for almost a day, but couldn't find any related information.

The only thing I found was an API with SteamFriends, there were some API's that retrieved the user's name and avatar image.

Here's the code I'm trying:

```csharp
private CallResult<LeaderboardScoresDownloaded_t> m_DownloadResult = new CallResult<LeaderboardScoresDownloaded_t>();

...

SteamAPICall_t hSteamAPICall = SteamUserStats.DownloadLeaderboardEntries(
    m_CurrentLeaderboard, 
    ELeaderboardDataRequest.k_ELeaderboardDataRequestGlobalAroundUser,
    -4,
    5
);
m_DownloadResult.Set(hSteamAPICall, OnLeaderboardDownloadScore);

...

void OnLeaderboardDownloadScore(LeaderboardScoresDownloaded_t pCallback, bool failure) {
    Debug.Log("Failure: " + failure);

    if (!failure) {
        int count = pCallback.m_cEntryCount;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            LeaderboardEntry_t leaderboardEntry;

            SteamUserStats.GetDownloadedLeaderboardEntry(
                pCallback.m_hSteamLeaderboardEntries,
                i,
                out leaderboardEntry,
                null,
            0);

            CSteamID user = leaderboardEntry.m_steamIDUser;

            Debug.Log("Rank" + i);
            Debug.Log("User Name: " + leaderboardEntry.    // how to get user name and avatar?
            Debug.Log(leaderboardEntry.m_nScore);


            Debug.Log("===========================");
        }
    }
}
```

In `LeaderboardEntry`, I can only get the `score` and `CSteamID`. In `SteamUser` and `SteamUserStat` classes, there was no API that can get the user's name and avatar image.

Comment: Friend, have you made any progress? I'm in the same dilemma, I'm doing it for the game maker.

Comment: @TiagoMartinelli Answers posts should be used to provide solutions to the question asked. If you have a new question, please use the Ask Question button at the top of the page.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [ISteamFriends](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/api/ISteamFriends).

Code for use with Steamworks.NET's [isteamfriends.cs](https://github.com/rlabrecque/Steamworks.NET/blob/master/com.rlabrecque.steamworks.net/Runtime/autogen/isteamfriends.cs):

```cs
public static string GetFriendlyName(CSteamID id)
{
    return SteamFriends.GetFriendPersonaName(id);
}

public static Texture2D GetAvatar(CSteamID id)
{
    // See docs for when this is valid. Also for other sizes.
    int avatar_id = SteamFriends.GetMediumFriendAvatar(id);
    Texture2D avatar = null;
    if (!SteamUtils.GetImageSize(avatar_id, out uint width, out uint height)
            && width > 0
            && height > 0)
    {
        var image = new byte[width * height * 4];
        SteamUtils.GetImageRGBA(avatar_id, image, (int)(width * height * 4));
        avatar = new Texture2D((int)width, (int)height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false, true);
        avatar.LoadRawTextureData(image);
        // Unity expects texture data to start from "bottom", so avatar
        // will be upside down. You could change the pixels here to fix it.

        avatar.Apply();
    }
    return avatar;
}
```

But you may want to consider using [Facepunch.Steamworks](https://github.com/Facepunch/Facepunch.Steamworks) which is more C#-friendly (async/await instead of callbacks, enumerables, etc). From their examples:

```cs
foreach ( var friend in SteamFriends.GetFriends() )
{
    Console.WriteLine( $"{friend.Id}: {friend.Name}" );
    Console.WriteLine( $"{friend.IsOnline} / {friend.SteamLevel}" );

    friend.SendMessage( "Hello Friend" );
}

var image = await SteamFriends.GetLargeAvatarAsync( steamid );
if ( !image.HasValue ) return DefaultImage;
return MakeTextureFromRGBA( image.Value.Data, image.Value.Width, image.Value.Height );
```

Answer (score 1):

`SteamFriends.GetFriendPersonaName(leaderboardEntry.m_steamIDUser)`

Comment: This looks like it answers half the question (how to get the username) - can you flesh this out into a more complete example?